# Allow_grow and allow_shrink in GWindow.widnow method in LablGtk2

Tags: window, gtk, ocaml

I made a window using GWindow.window method in LablGtk2. After compiling, I ran the program. Then, I got warnings.

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkWindow:allow-grow is deprecated 
and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkWindow:allow-shrink is deprecated 
and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
```

I want to enable a window to be grown and shrunk. So, I must use other optional arguments or methods instead of optional arguments "allow_grow" and "allow_shrink". However, I can't find proper optional arguments or methods. Can you tell me what to use instead of "allow_grow" and "allow_shrink"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for the `allow-grow` and `allow-shrink` properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--allow-grow) state that the replacement property is [`resizable`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--resizable). Note that the default value is `TRUE`, meaning [windows are resizable by default.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-resizable)

Note that the names `allow-grow` and `allow-shrink` are a bit of a misnomer, and lends itself to why they were separate at first: they determine whether a window can be made larger or smaller than the *size request* of the window (and its contents?), rather than arbitrarily by the user. The replacement makes a bit more sense (and you will need to use it if you choose to move to GTK+ 3).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I merely want to enable the user to resize a window, so I think `allow-grow` and `allow-shrink` are not necessary for me. I will delete them in my code. Again, thank you very much!